# Mapping financial data from multiple vendors to match internal formats and naming convention

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, data-processing, data-cleaning

I have a concern which I believe might be a good subject for the archives, as I imagine many people may encounter a similar problem at some point in their careers. I'm looking for any/all suggestions, ideas, comments in regards to mapping data between multiple vendors to a standard formats.

My story:

Currently, I receive two different categories of data (AKA "Constant" and "Variable"). containing a plethora of financial information [ie. loans, rates, mortgages, addresses, etc...]. Each vendor has their own format style and naming conventions different from my own.

Set 1) The Constant set: contains around 25 CSV files daily from different vendors. Each vendor has a different name (column-header) for the their data, however the format of their data is similar to mine.

Set 2) The Variable set: contains roughly 20 files, though their formats and header are almost always unique (ie. I have a data set named "Loan Rate", and my vendors call it "Rate", "LnRt", "rT", "PxrT", etc.. ). Therefore I need to go through each file, first clean the formatting of the data (proper case format, parsing the names in to different columns, converting date/time format, etc..) Then relabeling everything.

My current method of cleaning the data is by using an "Upload Template" in Excel. After I clean the formatting of all the data, I then copy values from the Vendor's file onto my Template. Then I have the data from the template loaded in a temp. table (Staging Table) on the SQL server. This is followed by running some SQL scripts to which in insert the values to the proper location within the database (DB).

As you might imagine, the entire process very tedious time consuming - to continue doing this manually is not really an option any more.

On to my questions:

1) Have you ever done something like this?  If so, how did you go about it?

2) Any ideas how to quickly change column names (headers) based on a list of names within 
another sheet?

3) Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the process?

4) Do you know of any software which can automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three letters: E. T. L.

Hit teh Googles, there are several ETL tools that are free.  You're re-inventing the wheel with your process.

Comment: Had I only known. Thanks you.